# Should we enforce code style in our large codebase?

Tags: architecture, open-source, code-quality, code-reviews, coding-style

By "code style" I mean 2 things:

1. Style, eg.

   ```
   // bad
   if(foo){ ... }

   // good
   if (foo) { ... }
   ```
2. Conventions and idiomaticity, where two ways of writing the same thing are functionally equivalent, but one is more idiomatic. eg.

   ```
   // bad
   if (fooLib.equals(a, b)) { ... }

   // good
   if (a == b) { ... }
   ```

I think it makes sense to use an auto-formatter to enforce #1 automatically. So my question is specifically about #2. I like to break things down into pros and cons, here's what I've come up with so far:

**Pros:**

- Used by many large codebases (eg. [Google](http://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/), [jQuery](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/))
- Helps make it a bit easier to work on new areas of the codebase
- Helps make code more portable (this is not necessarily true)
- Code style is automatic once you get used to it
- Makes it easier to fast-decline pull requests

**Cons:**

- Takes engineers’ and code reviewers’ time away from more important things (like developing features)
- Code should ideally be rewritten every 2-3 years anyway, so it’s more important to focus on getting the architecture right, and achieving high test coverage
- Adds strain to code reviews (eg. “don’t do it this way, I like this other way better”)
- Even if I’ve been using a code style for a while, I still sometime have to pause and think about how to write a line better
- Having an enforced, uniform code style makes it hard to experiment with potentially better styles
- Maintaining a style guide takes a lot of incremental effort
- Engineers rarely read through the style guide. More often, it's cited in code reviews

And as a secondary question: we also have many smaller repositories - should the same code style be enforced there?

Comment: Which language is this? The first one is barely noticeable, if some tool handle it great if not, who cares? The second one is a bit dependent on the actual language. So can't really say anything but, why bother :)

Comment: Use a linter or some program or tool that automatically enforces style.

Comment: @hkon this applies to any language. In the second example, let's say both work but only one is idiomatic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that would enforce the first type of code style, but I imagine writing a linter to enforce the second type would be very difficult, if possible at all

Comment: What's the second type? `==` vs. `Equals`?  That's what code reviews are for.

Comment: @eighttrackmind no it doesen't in Java they use equals in C# they use ==. Just an example...

Comment: @RobertHarvey see my edit in the original post. my question is, should engineers even spend time enforcing that type of style in code reviews?

Comment: `==` vs `Equals` is a non-trivial coding difference; i.e. the logic is not necessarily the same.  Yes, it matters.

Comment: @RobertHarvey for the sake of argument here, let's say that the equals `#equals()` implementation defers to `==`. this is just an example.

Comment: Then make a decision during one of the code reviews that we're either going to make them all look the same, or leave them the way they are.  It's not trivially automatable, so spending time on it if it doesn't matter may not make sense.

Comment: Most of your cons aren't really cons. Code styles shouldn't take time away from engineers or reviewers - it can be automatically set by an IDE or a pre-commit hook to change formatting. Code reviewers should be looking at well-formatted code so they can find other issues (things that can't be detected by static analysis or issues with the automated tests). Having a standard style doesn't mean someone can't propose a new style on a different project to try out and see what people think

Comment: @ThomasOwens see my reply below. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/253678/should-we-enforce-code-style-in-our-large-codebase#comment510397_253682

Answer (score 7):

Use a linter or some program or tool that automatically enforces style.  That should alleviate the objections about it taking too much time.

Most of the objections have to do with "I'm uncomfortable with *that* style."  It doesn't matter.  Coding conventions are all about uniformity.  Enforcing that uniformity will make code reviews easier by eliminating discussions about that, and allowing code reviews to focus on more substantial issues.

Comment: I'm not interested in the automatable part of code style (#1 above). I'm specifically asking opinions on the non-automatable part (ie. what's idiomatic, #2 above). Thanks!

Comment: That's covered under "more substantial issues" in my answer, above.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you need to use an **automated tool** which enforces style on every commit. **The applies to both examples from your question.** In .NET, the first piece of code will be enforced by StyleCop, while the second one—by Code analysis (for inspiration, see [CA1820](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182279.aspx)).

The goal of having a style guide is to:

- Enforce uniform style in order to make the code base easier to read and maintain by reducing the effort required by a different style than the one the reader usually uses. Example: tabs vs. spaces.
- Discourage situations where bugs are introduced more easily. For example, by forbidding to end the line of code by whitespace, you may mitigate the risk of introducing some bugs which are moreover difficult to pinpoint:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  cp·-r·/hello/world·\·     ← This space at the end is annoying.
        /demo/destination/
  ```

In both cases, rules can and should be automated.

Once you use an automated tool, the cons from your question become irrelevant.

> Takes engineers’ and code reviewers’ time away from more important things (like developing features)

If you use automatic style checker, correcting those errors at the beginning can waste some time to the authors, but with practice, it will quickly become a very easy task which takes in worst cases a few minutes.

> Code should ideally be rewritten every 2-3 years anyway, so it’s more important to focus on getting the architecture right, and achieving high test coverage

There is nothing to "focus" on. You write code, you commit it, if there is a style error, you correct it and commit again. And you do that while keeping all your focus on the readability of the code, maintainability, architecture, design and reliability/testing.

Also, why do you have to rewrite code every 2-3 years? Shouldn't you be concerned by the quality of the code which requires such time-costly rewriting?

> Adds strain to code reviews (eg. “don’t do it this way, I like this other way better”)

You shouldn't mention nor discuss style during code reviews.

> Even if I’ve been using a code style for a while, I still sometime have to pause and think about how to write a line better

Better as opposed to compliant to the style guide? In four years using StyleCop and a few months using PEP 8, I never found myself in a situation where adopting a non-uniform style would *substantially* improve the readability.

> Having an enforced, uniform code style makes it hard to experiment with potentially better styles

Which doesn't matter. Frankly, there is no right answer to whether you should use tabs or spaces or whether you should put `{` on a new line. There is nothing to experiment with. Most rules are somehow arbitrary: what counts is not *which* rule was chosen, but the fact that the rule *was* chosen and is now enforced, making the code base consistent.

Note that you shouldn't follow style rules religiously, without understanding why are they written in their current form. Some rules (tabs vs. spaces) really don't have a convincing explanation. Others have an interesting reasoning. For example, this piece of code:

```
var demo = [
    someElementHere,
    anotherOne,
    helloWorld,
    goodBye,
];
```

is better than:

```
var demo = [
    someElementHere,
    anotherOne,
    helloWorld,
    goodBye       ← Noticed the lack of comma?
];
```

Why? Because in the first case, if you add a new element to the array and commit, the commit consists of *one new line*. In the second piece of code, the commit will consist of *one new line and one modified line*. The first one is semantically more correct in a diff.

Another interesting example is [code used to advertise jsHint](http://anton.kovalyov.net/p/why-jshint/) as being better than Douglas Crockford's jsLint. The code [contains a mistake](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/200927/6605) which is not obvious to see by a beginner. jsLint catches this mistake and displays a error. jsHint doesn't catch it, letting you to find it yourself when one day, in production, the web app starts behaving unexpectedly.

> Maintaining a style guide takes a lot of incremental effort

Don't reinvent the wheel. Most languages already have a style guide. A benefit of using an existent one is that most newcomers will already know it, whereas nobody will know yours.

> Engineers rarely read through the style guide. More often, it's cited in code reviews

That's why it should be enforced during commits.

Now your main question:

### Should we enforce code style in our large codebase?

Ask your team. Is code style inconsistency an issue for your team? Are at least some members constantly complaining about the style of their pairs? Do you have commits which intentionally change style, and only style? Do you have unreadable diffs because someone decided to replace all tabs by spaces or add spaces before and after each parenthesis?

- **If yes, you have to enforce code style.** Otherwise, the team members are wasting their time.

  Note that this task is not easy. You want to avoid discussions about which style is better at all costs: otherwise, you'll find yourself making compromises, and finally, you'll end up with no style enforcement at all.

  If you're interested in the difficulties of introducing a style into an existent code base, ask a separate question, and I'll be happy answering it in more detail.
- **If not, don't bring the subject.** Team members are happy with the current inconsistency, or at least they learnt to deal with it. Many developers are in this case: often, ones who switched jobs a lot or who used a lot of different programming languages can't care less and are able to read and understand code with any style.

  Enforcing style in this case would only slow things down. The team would be forced to walk through the entire code base. The bigger is the code base, the harder is to fix the style. If the code is not tested enough, there is also a risk of introducing regressions.

Comment: To clarify, I propose there are 2 kinds of code style: (1) Code style that is automatable (spacing, tabs, etc.), and (2) Code style that is not automatable (ie. What is idiomatic, “this line can be better written like this”).
Since the cost of enforcing #1 is near-zero (if we use automated tooling), I’m asking specifically about the 2nd kind of code style.

Comment: @eighttrackmind: can you please give an example? Both examples from your question can easily be checked with an automated checker.

Comment: I don't want to get lost in specific examples. The point is that there exists a class of code review comment that is somewhere between simple code style (eg. spacing) and architecture-level comments. Here's another trivial example, creating a new array of 100 "foo"s in javascript: https://gist.github.com/eighttrackmind/8382e78b0712f628889b

Comment: @eighttrackmind: examples are important; you claim that some style rules cannot be automated, but cannot give an illustration. Both examples from your question are easily automated. As for 100 "foo"s, jsLint would invalidate option 2 (as well as option 1, but that's more subtle); then, enforcing functional style in an automated tool won't be difficult either.

Comment: @eighttrackmind: maybe you believe that linters are no more complicated than `grep`. In reality, they are much more than that, and in order to be convinced, look at the rules of jsLint of Code analysis (including the link to CA1820 in my answer).

Comment: I'd love a linter that does more than simple jshint-style checks. but from what i've found, that doesn't exist (at least for javascript). i actually compiled a list here - https://gist.github.com/eighttrackmind/cf7d045d2d0a73bc3e5c. so in the meantime, we likely have to either manually enforce stuff like this through code review, or choose not to enforce it.

Answer (score -1):

I think the code style works the other way -- it helps reviewer understand the code easier, save their time, and helps maintenance in the future.

Also, reviewers shouldn't force others to use a code style, but they should point things out if that gonna cause some trouble (especially seniors).

Automatic style tool should be ok but also should be optional -- as some developer might not like to style their code for some reasons.

Comment: I don't care if a developer _likes_ a particular style or not. The _group_ needs to have a consistent style.